# parent, child and grandchild using fork() and exec()

Tags: c, process, exec, fork

I am trying to create a program that will repeat the execution of ./program lots of times spread over 3 fork()ed processes. Each process will have its own set of numbers to use as input for ./program. 
As the exec function would end the process I have each child process forking to grandchildren processes in order to carry out the execvp(./program). This is the code I have so far but it doesn't seem quite right, I have tried to debug it with gdb but just got even more confused. Currently it ends with Abort Trap 6 - Any suggestions or advise would be much appreciated thanks.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

pid_t children[3];
int x = 0;
int minRange = 0;
int maxRange = 0;
int totalMax = 2000;
int numProcesses = 0;


if(argc != 2)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: invalid arguments.\n\n");
    return 1;
}



numProcesses = atoi(argv[1]);

for (x = 0; x < numProcesses; x++) 
{
    minRange = ((totalMax / numProcesses) * x);
    maxRange = ((totalMax / numProcesses) * (x + 1));


    children[x] = fork();

    if(children[x] == 0)
    {
        pid_t g_pid;
        int i;

        for(i = minRange; i < maxRange; i++)
        {
            printf("\n\n here 2 \n\n");
            g_pid = fork();

            if(g_pid == 0)
            {
                printf("\n\n here s \n\n");
                char *argv[4];


                argv[0] = "./program";
                argv[1] = "numtest.txt";
                argv[2] = "435";
                argv[3] = NULL;


                execvp(argv[0], argv);

            }
            break;

        }
        break;
    }   
    else
        continue;   

}
```

}

Comment: Maybe your system doesn't allow you to create 2000 processes. Does it work if you set `totalMax` to 10? I don't understand why you need the three levels. Can't the parent handle all 2000 children?

Comment: Its more about splitting the load into three processes all up. And I need the third level otherwise the three child processes would die after execvp() was called.